# Two maven dependencies from different repos

Tags: java, maven, selenium, sikuli

How can i use selenium and sikuli in one pom.xml ?

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.45.0</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
        <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

sikuli is in :

```
<repository>
        <id>com.sikulix</id>
        <name>com.sikulix</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
```

but adding this repo, makes maven to look there for selenium too

is it possible to link two different dependencies from two different repositories ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven looks for artifacts (selenium, sikulixapi, ..) in all defined repositories.

You can define two: com.sikulix and the standard one:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>com.sikulix</id>
    <name>com.sikulix</name>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
<repository>
  <id>central</id>
  <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
  <layout>default</layout>
  <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </snapshots>
</repository>
```